# jquery wont send with post method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

nothing is being sent with $.post

```
     function clicked()
 {
   var $contact_title=$("#contact_title");
   var $contact_summary=$("#bbcode");
   alert($contact_title.val());// How do I get the contents of the title
   alert($contact_summary.val());// How do I get the contents of the textarea
   $.post('jquery_send_admin.php',{ title:$contact_title, content:$contact_summary }, function(data){ alert("Message was sent") }, 'html');
 }
```

I get exceptions in my console error..like the following:

UPDATE:
no data is inserted on the next page..why?!?

```
     if( isset($_POST["title"]) && isset($_POST["content"]) )
  {
      $title=mysql_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
      $content=mysql_escape_string($_POST["content"]);

       $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (query_title,query_message) VALUES(''$title', '$content')") or die(mysql_error());

   }
```

The following error happens:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 16"  data: no]
```

UPDATE:
Thats what I request from the page, which is triggered by jquery:

```
    <?php
echo 'outside';
  if( isset($_POST["title"]) && isset($_POST["content"]) )
  {
      echo 'inside';
      $title=mysql_escape_string($_POST["title"]);
      $content=mysql_escape_string($_POST["content"]);

       $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (query_title,query_message) VALUES(''$title', '$content')") or die(mysql_error());

   }

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to extract the values using the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

```
var $contact_title = $('#contact_title').val();
var $contact_summary = $('#bbcode').val();
var dataToPost = { title: $contact_title, content: $contact_summary };
$.post('jquery_send_admin.php', dataToPost, function(data) { 
    alert('Message was sent'); 
}, 'html');
```

Comment: why I dont get anything put inside on the next page?!?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd, what next page are you talking about? What do you expect to get on this next page and what are you actually getting?

Comment: In my update, as you see in my update, I am trying to insert data.. and hte alert message isnt being triggered at the end..why?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd, where/how are you calling this `clicked` function? Make sure to cancel any default actions if you are doing this on some submit button or anchor click.

Comment: It is a button..<input name="send" type="button" onClick="clicked()" value="Send" />.. Look at the update. I posted my error

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd, do you return HTML from your `jquery_send_admin.php` script? In the $.post you have indicated html as last argument so make sure you return html from the script.

Comment: I do this... var $results=$.post('jquery_send_admin.php',{ title:$contact_title, content:$contact_summary }, function(data){ alert("Message was sent") }, 'html');
   alert($results);....... But the alert doesnt pop up

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd, you didn't answer my question: do you return HTML from your **PHP** script? If not, then remove the `'html'` argument from your `$.post` call.

Comment: @Dmitry Makovetskiyd, yeah, few echos, but you are not echoing html. This is what jQuery expects in return of your PHP script because this is what you indicated it when calling the $.post method. So remove this last argument if you do not intend to return real HTML from your PHP script.

Comment: Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 16"  data: no]

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd, are you calling the `.val()` method exactly as shown in my answer? If you alert the value of the `$contact_title` variable what do you see? Please show your exact code.

Comment: It works now.... but my database is not updated... if I use echo// can I test if I have a mysql_error?!? when results are returned?!?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd, sorry I know nothing about PHP. I guess there is a way to debug your scripts?

Comment: How do I retreive the response value from teh post

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd, it will be passed as the `data` parameter of your anonymous callback which is invoked in case of success.

Answer (score 1):

try to get the value/text instead of just the control.

```
var $contact_title=$("#contact_title").text();
```

or

```
var $contact_title=$("#contact_title").val();
```

Edit:

Not sure how it works in PHP but I use it with vb.net and there I need to give my controller name(aka file) and function so it becomes

```
$.post('myFile/myJSONFunction', {all-your-parameters});
```

So maybe thats why it wont post your data.
Something else you might want to look at is that your php might return different data than you are actually expecting him to return.

Comment: the text doesnt work, the val() does..but The post method doesnt

Answer (score 1):

```
 var $contact_title=$("#contact_title").text();
   var $contact_summary=$("#bbcode").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clicked() {
         var $contact_title = $("#contact_title");
         var $contact_summary = $("#bbcode");
         alert($contact_title.val()); // with the val
         alert($contact_summary.val()); // with the val
         $.post('jquery_send_admin.php', { title: $contact_title.val(), content: $contact_summary.val() }, function (data) { alert("Message was sent") }, 'html');
     }
```

Comment: the post fails to post to the page... see the exception that is uncaught

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this posted by @Darin

```
$.post('jquery_send_admin.php', dataToPost, function(data) { 
    alert('Message was sent'); 
}, 'html');
```

use this

```
$.post('jquery_send_admin.php', dataToPost, function(data) { 
    alert(data); 
});
```

That will show the result of the echo statements in the alert box which could possibly help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my. jQuery bugs, PHP debugging bugs. I'll probably get down-rates for this answer... but sometimes, it helps to simply read the manuals if you're that lost that people have to help you cross the street: http://api.jquery.com/ & http://php.net/manual/